# Bitbucket git pull not working when connected to hotspot

Tags: networking, ssh, git, android

I can use git (bitbucket) without any problem when I am connected to a regular Wifi.

However, when I do Wifi tethering using my mobile device (Android) as hotspot a simple `git pull` takes soo much time that I have to cancel.

I can browse the Internet normally, no problems, however a `git pull/push` doesn't work.

I can see that it can connect to bitbucket.

Once I disconnect and connect to the Wifi the `git pull/push` works.

Any thoughts?

thank you

Comment: I would install Termux on the device and test if git pull/push works better when directly using mobile network without hotspot in between.

Comment: I need the connection from the Android device, the macbook have access to the Internet from the Android device.
When I close the Android hotspot and connect the laptop to any Wifi bitbucket works just fine.

Comment: I was suggesting to test git on Android directly without hotspot.